# IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE Avoiding Duplicates using 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, not-exists

I'm new at this again. I say again because my first intro to SQL was on an AS400 in 1992.

I realize that there have been a few similar posts. I have tried to get ideas from each to solve my problem, but little to NO success. Here is what I am trying to do. There are 3 tables. Two Source Tables and one Target Table. Source Tables are Tickets and TicketEntities and the target table is DelTimes.

`Tickets` has columns:

```
(Id (primary), TicketNumber, LastUpdateTime and LastOrderDate, DepartmentId)
```

`TicketEntities` has columns:

```
(Ticket_Id, EntityTypeId, EntityName)
```

Target Table `DelTimes` has:

```
(TicketId, TicketNo, TicketDate, LOTime, LOMinutes, DriverNam)
```

The `lastOrderDate` and `LastUpdateTime` are Date and Time Combined that I have to extract info from using convert.

Here is what I have got so far with error multi-part identifier issues.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tickets, TicketEntities Where Tickets.DepartmentId = 2 and EntityTypeId = 3)
    UPDATE DelTimes
            SET TicketId =Tickets.Id, 
                DelTimes.TicketNo = Tickets.TicketNumber, 
                DelTimes.TicketDate = CONVERT(Date,Tickets.LastOrderDate,5),
                DelTimes.LOTime = Convert(datetime,Tickets.LastOrderDate,8), 
                DelTimes.LOMinutes = DATEDIFF(minute,Tickets.LastOrderDate,Tickets.LastUpdateTime),
                DelTimes.DriverNam = TicketEntities.EntityName
ELSE
    INSERT INTO DelTimes (TicketId, TicketNo, TicketDate, LOTime, LOMinutes, DriverNam)
                         VALUES (Id, TicketNumber, CONVERT(Date,LastOrderDate,5), 
                         Convert(datetime,LastOrderDate,8),
                         DATEDIFF(minute,LastOrderDate,LastUpdateTime),
                                      EntityName)
```

Your help in solving this is appreciated!

Comment: Format code. More people will try and help.

Comment: It does not look like other posts How is that done?

Comment: With 4 spaces. I will edit it for you.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  What is not working properly?

Comment: The error I'm getting is Multi-part Identifier .on Ticket.Id obviously it's the first on the list.  I tried as was suggested elsewhere using eg. Ticket.Id  as tktid.  no luck error became 'AS'

Comment: Thank You for the help in Formatting and final edit!

Comment: I think you are missing the `WHERE` clause for the update, or do you want to edit all entries of the target table? And shouldn't you be looking if the entry exists in the target table to decide whether to update or insert?

Comment: Recommend studying up on the MERGE statement - It will really simplify and make your code more readable too. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Your `ELSE` statement looks like it should be a `SELECT` rather than a `VALUES` statement. Create a `SELECT` statement that would select the data you want to insert and put it in place of your `VALUES` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is the answer because you don't have variables, joins between tables or WHERE clauses. But for someone just starting out, it will probably end up lookings something like:

```
     UPDATE DelTimes
                SET DelTimes.TicketNo = Tickets.TicketNumber, 
                    DelTimes.TicketDate = CONVERT(Date,Tickets.LastOrderDate,5),
                    DelTimes.LOTime = Convert(datetime,Tickets.LastOrderDate,8), 
                    DelTimes.LOMinutes = DATEDIFF(minute,Tickets.LastOrderDate,
Tickets.LastUpdateTime),
                    DelTimes.DriverNam = @DriverName
        FROM DelTimes
        JOIN Tickets ON DelTimes.TicketId = Tickets.TicketId
        JOIN TicketEntities ON TicketEntities.Ticket_Id =  Tickets.TicketId 
        WHERE DelTimes.TicketId = @TicketId
              AND TicketEntities.EntityTypeId = 3


    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO DelTimes (TicketId, TicketNo, TicketDate, LOTime, LOMinutes, DriverNam)
             VALUES (@TicketId, @TicketNumber, CONVERT(Date,@LastOrderDate,5), 
                Convert(datetime,@LastOrderDate,8),
                DATEDIFF(minute,@LastOrderDate,@LastUpdateTime),  
                @DriverName)
```

I'm probably doing more harm than good here and their is a lot about this I don't like, but this will get you started. (To the next round of questions.)